# ggplot legend shows wrong shapes on legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to set up custom labels and shapes for my 2 points A and B. The labels are set correctly to A and B, respectively. Why is the shape not showing correctly? It should be shape 2 and 3 respectively. Instead it is a combination of 2 and 3 for both points.

```
library(ggplot2) 
ggplot(data.frame(), aes()) +
  geom_point(aes(x = 3, y = 0, col='A'), shape=2) +
  geom_point(aes(x = 5, y = 0, col='B'), shape=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Try moving the `shape` inside `aes()`, using the same labels as for `color` (i.e., "A" and "B"). Then set the shapes via `values` in `scale_shape_manual()`.

Comment: @aosmith I am seeing the error: `Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale`. Also, I just noticed a weird "3" and "0" at the x and y axis that is not intended. I am simply trying to understand legends in ggplot. Seems unnecessarily hard.

Comment: IMO legends are most straightforward in ggplot2 when mapping aesthetics to variables. If you want to set to constants and get legends you usually need more steps. I talk about the basics [in this blog post](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/07/19/manual-legends-ggplot2/) but don't get into using this approach for multiple aesthetics.

Comment: Note that to combine legends the legends must share the same name, which doesn't happen when setting aesthetics to constants. Then you'd need to do that manually. See: `+ scale_shape_manual(name = "legend", values = c(1, 3)) + scale_color_discrete(name = "legend")` after moving `shape` into `aes()` with "A" and "B" constants.